# Disabling hyperthreading

Tags: 18.04, grub2

I'm trying to disable hyperthreading in an AMD (EPYC-2) machine running on Ubuntu 18.04. One of the procedures to achieve this with Intel processors involves adding 'noht' to the "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX" line in /etc/default/grub? However, and after rebooting my system, it is still in hyperthreading mode. I'm not even sure if the syntax is the same for Intel and AMD processors, does anyone have any experience trying to accomplish this goal?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The OS is not allowing me to modify the kernel parameters. It's an Azure vm so Microsoft has likely blocked this type of modifications.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your kernel command line contains the new kernel parameter by checking with:

```
cat /proc/cmdline
```

Also ensure /boot/grub/grub.cfg has been updated by running `sudo update-grub` before rebooting.